# filesystem could not be mouted: /run when do lxc-start

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lxc

I have installed lxc in ubuntu server, every thing was working fine. Today I have updated lxc from version 0.7.5 to version 1.0.0.alpha2. After I update lxc, I am unable to start lxc containers.

```
lxc-ls:

ContainerOne containerTwo ContainerThree.
```

I have created these containers in version 0.7.5.

After update to 1.0.0.alpha2 I try to start container as

```
lxc-start -n ContainerOne

Result:

<4> init: ureadahead main process (7) terminated with status 5 
. 
.
.
mountall: mount /run [34] terminated with status 32 
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /run
```

What is the error? How can I solve this problem? I have restarted server but no luck.

**Additional Info:**

I have mounted lxc lib and cache in different file system when I installed lxc for first time. Entry in fstab file:

```
/home/lxclib /var/lib/lxc none defaults, bind 0 0 /home/lxccache /var/cache/lxc none defaults, bind 0 0
```

I am able to create and start new containers but can't start old containers.

**Edit:**
I did update lxc while all the three containers started, Is this the problem?